# Installing XP to external hard drive for another PC

Tags: windows-xp, installation, external-hard-drive

I have two laptops, and have removed the harddrive from laptop number one and formatted it. Is it possible to install Xp Pro (from CD) onto the harddrive (using external usb cable) from laptop number two as laptop number one doesn't have a CD drive.

Hope you can offer advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might not work as When XP boots up normally, it resets the USB bus and re-detects all of the hardware. Unfortunately when this happens and your boot device is the USB device, your USB device becomes inaccessible and XP blue screens before it loads.

But still I am not sure, besides when you choose that particular disk to install Windows would probably put out an error message.

Having said that some sites offer some hard tricks like these over here http://www.ehow.com/how_4853554_install-xp-external-hard-drive.html

Other Solution which comes to my mind are

- installing your hard-disk as an external hard-disk in some other computer
- Installing Windows to your Laptop using USB pendrive rather than a CD

Comment: Original article and author here....

http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176

Comment: ngine's tricks Never worked for me , I have tried them hundred times

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to get an external USB CD drive and install XP onto laptop one's hard drive directly.